# Python Open and Save Most Recent Files in Different Subfolders with Win32com

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I have a main folder that has 37subfolders, each subfolder contains multiple files, I want to open the most recent file in each subfolder, then save and close using win32. My code works just fine but its opening and saving only one file in one subfolder, I need the code to open, save and close the most recent file in each of 37subfolders rather than just one. See my code below:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import glob
from win32com.client import Dispatch

main = r'C:\Users\me\Documents\themainfolder'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(main):
    for folders in subdirs:
       latest_file = max(glob.glob(f"{os.path.join(path, folders)}/*.xlsm"),key=os.path.getmtime))
    
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(latest_file)
xlBook.Save()
xlBook.Close()
```

PS: The reason I am doing this is because files were saved with openpyxl but R studio is not able to read them properly(it reads them but reads them wrong) I don't know why but I found that just manually opening the files and saving them again fixes the problem however, I cannot manually reopen and save each of the files, so I did a test and found that using win32 to reopen and save the files also fixes the problem.

Comment: On the give code, the opening & saving is not inside the loop, and so only happens for the last value of `latest_file`. Create the `xlApp` object before the loop, open/save/close the files within the loop. (ie don't keep calling `Dispatch`).

Comment: @DS_London and to think I lost sleep trying to figure it out. Thank You! I did what you said and it worked like a charm, it opened and closed all the most recently modified files in each subfolders. I will paste the correct code below for people that may have similar problem so they don't lose sleep like me lol

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anybody out there here is the correct code that works to opeb abd close most recent files in each subfolders of a directory

```
from pathlib import Path
import glob
from win32com.client import Dispatch


xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application") #call dispatch just once, dispatching multiple times causes issues(I think)
xlApp.Visible = False  #this will prevent the file from visibly opening

main = r'C:\Users\me\Documents\themainfolder'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(main):
    for folders in subdirs:
        latest_file = max(glob.glob(f"{os.path.join(path, folders)}/*.xlsm"),key=os.path.getmtime)
        print(latest_file) #just to double check that it got the latest files
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(latest_file)
        xlBook.Save()
        xlBook.Close()
```